# How to select a UUID from a prepared statement in Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to select a user based on a UUID:

```
const client = await this.pg.connect()
const { rowsAct } = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=$1`, [
  userUUID
])
```

I also tried without the variable:

```
const client = await this.pg.connect()
const { rowsAct } = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=$1`, [
  '4fcf0ca3-4e26-40a9-bbe5-78ff8fdb6e0f'
])
```

I tried using ::uuid casting but maybe I did it wrong. The returned `rowsAct` is always undefined.

I verified the `userUUID` variable was populated and was a valid uuid:
    console.log(typeof userUUID) // string

What am I doing wrong? How can I properly select a row form it's UUID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your argument in parentheses before applying the `::uuid` type cast so that the prepared statement can properly interpolate argument.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ($1)::uuid
```

You can also cast the column itself to `text` but it's less performant since the query will have to cast each row.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid::text = $1
```

Comment: The first one is better because that can make use of an index on `uid`

Comment: Oh thanks I was still hurting my head with that one! :D